# get the data in the textfield and create an object React JS

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UHBz.png)

How can i get the data in the textfield and create an object like

```
{
  "Name" : "Hoang Viet",
  "Age"  : 21,
  "City" : "Quy Nhon"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would go about constructing the object pretty much. Assuming you know how to get the values of from the text fields,

```js
const obj = {
  Name: txtNameFieldValue,
  Age: txtAgeFieldValue,
  City: txtCityFieldValue
};
```

Comment: oh no, cause all values can be edit, it's not const

Comment: I was just giving you an idea. its up to you how you want to implement it. let or const or anything else.